# Is $.proxy a code smell?

Tags: javascript, code-smell

I've been writing most of my javascript applications in an OO style close to what I would use for most other languages. However, this means that most callbacks need to have a reference to an object, and I generally handle that by using $.proxy (or dojo.hitch, or whatever the framework's tool for this is) to be sure that the callbacks are operating in the context of my object, rather than the tag they were attached to.

Very quickly, this seems to lead to using proxied calls for almost everything, and can look like I'm fighting against the tool, particularly if the tool is jQuery.

Do you have a policy on how to handle javascript function binding in your work? Do you try fit your design to how the tool binds it's functions, or do you force the bindings to work according to your design?

Comment: Can you precise why you don't generally simply use closures or inline functions ?

Comment: Neither scales past a certain level of complexity, and they both present the same issue, where jQuery blows away the current object scope. Stuffing a bunch of variables just so that I have access to them in the closure seems like a worse solution.

Comment: I know people often try to refute this fact, but the developer of JavaScript, Brendan Eich himself claimed ["I was recruited to Netscape with the promise of “doing Scheme” in the browser."](https://brendaneich.com/2008/04/popularity/) which is functional and based entirely on using lexical closures. Using JavaScript as an OO language is going against the grain, regardless of what many people may believe. [JQuery embraces this fact](http://www.windley.com/archives/2009/01/jquery_monads_and_functional_programming.shtml), which is part of why it's so successful.

Comment: If you think $.proxy has a chance of better scaling than closures or inline functions, then you probably should have a look at the [source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js) (look for "proxy:")

Comment: A code example of what you're trying to do would be helpful - it sounds like what you *want* is something like the [module pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html), but you might be trying to do it using OO methods.

Comment: @dystroy By scaling I mean that it scales with complexity - I'm not going to have to refactor it for DRY reasons once a few more features get added. If it's got severe performance penalties, then that's the kind of thing I'm asking about.

Comment: @JimmyHoffa the only functional features Javascript has, pretty much every other language has too. And those languages have critical basic features Javascript is missing so they don't need a closure for everything. Going against the grain? The whole standard library, DOM API, jQuery are implemented as OO. The jQuery "classes" (Event, jQuery, setFilters, Tween) are easily extensible, whereas with a closure implementation they would be cast in concrete. jQuery's popularity is because of its easy-to-use internal DSL API which enables non-programmers to do useful stuff with it.

Comment: @Esailija jQuery is a monadic api with internal continuation pumps, you can say that it's OO but there's nothing OO about that style or implementation. the DOM has nothing to do with javascript, that's strictly an implementation of the browser. Also, in javascript closures have a type similar to lambda-mu, that is not typical of non-functional languages. Furthermore, no, most languages do *not* have arbitrary depth lexically scoped closures, sorry to burst your bubble..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496932/is-jquery-a-monad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the alternatives to function binding are a lot worse, instead of a simple $.proxy call, the 
popular alternative is to type this every time

```
var self = this;
$().click( function(e) {
    self.doit(e);
});
```

Compared to

```
$().click($.proxy(this.doit, this));
```

I have an [active feature request](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12031) for jQuery where this would be possible:

```
$().click(this);
```

This is what the [standard event listener api supports](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventListener):

```
elem.addEventListener("click", this);
```

The method `.handleEvent` is then called on `this` when the event occurs, with proper context. The element
as `this` is just useless because it can be always attained from `event.currentTarget`.

So it's not a code smell in that you could replace it with something simpler or better.

Answer (score 3):

If you need the context for multiple functions, I agree with Esailija's solution.  It's common and simple.

If you only need it once, this is also available:

```
$().click( function(e) {
    this.do_something();
}.bind(this) );
```

If `do_something` takes no arguments (so it'll discard the `e`) and the anonymous function would only call it, I believe this also works:

```
$().click( this.do_something.bind(this) );
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function to which you're binding is simple (no return value, no arguments), $.proxy seems like the simplest option (plus, it has other functionality).

However, since you mentioned that you've "been writing most of my javascript applications in an OO style close to what I would use for most other languages", I highly recommend TypeScript and its lambda syntax.  I've provided a relevant example below, but first, an intro:

CoffeeScript, Google Dart, and other more mature languages have similar goals, but I'm not familiar with those--what you use will depend on the development tools and languages with which you're most comfortable.  If you use Microsoft languages and development tools, TypeScript is probably the best option (JetBrains IDEs have strong TypeScript support, as well).

I recently started implementing TypeScript in my projects because it brings object orientation to JavaScript and works well with .NET server-side languages (the open-source TypeLite makes it easy to automatically generate TypeScript interfaces from .NET classes: http://type.litesolutions.net/).  Although TypeScript is a Microsoft-initiated product, it's an open-source language.  For example, JetBrains' WebStorm IDE supports TypeScript more thoroughly than Visual Studio at this point; I use WebStorm along with Visual Studio for that reason.

I just realized that the OO-specific problem with $.proxy is that you can't enforce strongly-typed method arguments and return values.  But if you use lambdas in TypeScript (syntax that will be available in ECMAScript 6), you ***can*** enforce that without writing all the extra code required in ECMAScript 5.  Here's a working TypeScript example:

```
interface ICallbackData{
Value1: boolean;
Value2: string; 
}

class Manager{
    private _CallbackProxy: (CallbackData: ICallbackData)=>string;
    constructor(){
        this._CallbackProxy = (CallbackData)=>this.CallbackHandler(CallbackData);
    }   
    CallbackHandler(CallbackData: ICallbackData): string{
        if (CallbackData.Value1){
            return CallbackData.Value2;
        }
        return "Other String";
    }

    Value: number;
    PerformActionThenCallback(){
        this.Value += 1;
        this._CallbackProxy(<ICallbackData>{Value1: true, Value2: "Callback String, Value: " + this.Value.toString()});
    }
}
```

You can see the JavaScript to which that code will compile by plugging it in here: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

TypeScript will be ready for the future of ECMAScript, so you won't have to rewrite or upgrade your code.  For example, lambda functions written in TypeScript currently compile similar to what Esailija wrote (the alternative to $.proxy):

```
var self = this;
$().click( function(e) {
    self.doit(e);
});
```

It compiles to that because it is trying to be compatible with as many browsers' ECMAScript 5 implementations (it can currently compile to be compatible with ECMAScript 3 or 5; I'm not sure why it doesn't compile using .bind() for ECMAScript 5--that's a different topic).  But when ECMAScript 6 is widespread, TypeScript lambdas will compile directly as lambdas without generating all that extra code.  For now, though, at least there are robust OO languages that compile to JavaScript and simplify OO requirements, while eliminating the need to wait for ECMAScript 6 and beyond.